# What is the new time complexity after sorting an array with TO O(n*log(N))and then attaching a task to it with TO of O(n)?

Tags: big-o

How does my time complexity change after I using the mergeSort algorithm and then do a task with that sorted array with Time Complexity of O(N) does it become O(n^2*log(N))? or does it remain o(n*log(N))?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

It will remain O(N*log(N)) as O notation takes the upper bound of any function.
=> TO = O(N*log(N)) + O(n) = O(N*log(N))

Answer (score 0):

It would only become O(N^2 * log(N)) if you were adding operations that made the sort do something with each element (multiplying by N).

Since you're adding N operations after the sort is complete, the time complexity becomes O(N * log(N) + N). Since N is a lower order term, you can drop it and say the algorithm is still O(N * log(N)).